# Dynamically creating a JSF form with java reflection

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, reflection, crud

I'm trying to create a simple crud form to insert data into a database with hibernate, without knowing what the object type is. The ultimate goal is to only have one insert form for every table in the database. So far i get the methods that the current object has, check to see if it has any set methods and create a text input for every field that has a set.

```
UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
HtmlPanelGrid hpg = (HtmlPanelGrid) viewRoot.findComponent("panel");
    for (Method method : declaredFields) {
        String name = method.getName();

        if (name.contains("set")) {
            HtmlOutputText hot = new HtmlOutputText();
            HtmlInputText hit = new HtmlInputText();
            hot.setValue(name.substring(3));
            try {
                hit.setValue(newObject.getClass().getMethod(name, String.class));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ReflectController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            hpg.getChildren().add(hot);
            hpg.getChildren().add(hit);
        }

    }
```

Here newObject is the object that is going to be inserted into the database later with hibernate. My problem is this:

How do assign a certain field from that object to the text input that is being created at the moment. So far if I put the method in the value like I'm doing above, it will just print out the method in the value attribute for that input. what i want is that when this form is submited, for to assign the value in that text box to the property with that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you a partial answer - You need to create a ValueExpression dynamically

```
    Application app = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
    hit.setValueExpression("value", app.getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{bean.item}", Item.class));
```

The hard part will be creating the valueExpression  that will actually map to a field within your object's value. That requires a great deal more thought but you will for sure need the dynamic valueExpression. As written, this will result in the execution of your bean's setItem();method with a parameter of type Item.  You will require something a little more complex.

Answer (score 2):

In JSF, binding input components to properties is accomplished with EL-expressions. You can create one programmatically as Steve shows, but that syntax is really ugly. On a related note, programmatic manipulation of the component tree is a rather unorthodox way of using JSF. The orthodox way to tackle your requirement would be something like:

```
<ui:repeat var="prop" value="#{genericEditorBean.propertyNames}">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{prop}" for="input"/>
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{genericEditorBean.object[prop]}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

where

```
public List<String> getPropertyNames() {
    List<String> propertyNames = new ArrayList<>();
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(object.getClass());
    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        propertyNames.add(pd.getName());
    }
    return propertyNames;
}
```

(There really is no reason to reimplement scanning for Java Bean properties when the Java API offers a class for that very purpose. Unlike your home-grown version, this will also handle properties inherited from a super class ...)

Answer (score 2):

I once used an open-source library named *MetaWidget* to do this.

It was a few years ago, but it worked well and was easy to set up.

It looks like the project is still active:

- http://metawidget.sourceforge.net/index.php